# Responsive grid main menu

Tags: flutter, dart

so i want to build this kind of menu but the problem is when i try on another emulator it's foverflowed pixel, i don't understand the different between mainAxisSpacing & mainAxisExtent and how to use it properly. How do i fix this ?

[image]

[image]

Here is the code

```
GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        mainAxisSpacing: 26,
      ),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: MenuList.mainMenuList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
        var list = MenuList.mainMenuList[index];
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, list['route']);
          },
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 56,
                height: 56,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.white,
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
                    ],
                  ),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      offset:
                          Offset(0, 0), // x, y changes position of shadow
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    list['image_url'].toString(),
                    height: 38,
                    width: 38,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 12),
              Text(
                list["label"].toString(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: Constants.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expanded widget which will resize the image if available space is small for example

```dart
SizedBox(
 height: 60,
 width : 40,
 child: Column(
   children: [
//expanded will utilise the space left after the text and fill it with the image
    Expanded( 
      child: Image.asset(),
    ),
    Text("title here"),
   ]
 )
)
```